# How to use USB to RS232 communication with Android Things

Tags: serial-port, android-things

I am using MAX232 device for UART(Raspberry Pi) to RS232 communication(Other Board).
But I want to use USB to Serial cable for this. I have attached the image of a cable. How can I use this in Android Things?

Can anyone tell this.

[image]

Comment: I can point you to the [Android USB host documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) although can't provide additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like [this](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) or [that](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android). And in case of [FTDI-based](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) USB<->UART converters you can use [FTDI's solution for Android](https://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm) like [d2xx](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_134_FTDI_Android_D2XX_Driver.pdf) driver with [Java wrapper](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_JAVA_D2XX_Projects.htm). And you can find many examples (like [this](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-FTDI-UART-Sample/blob/master/src/com/ksksue/app/ftdi_uart/MainActivity.java)) of it's use:

```
...
private static D2xxManager ftD2xx = null;
private FT_Device ftDev;
...

try {
    ftD2xx = D2xxManager.getInstance(this);

    int devCount = 0;
    devCount = ftD2xx.createDeviceInfoList(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "Device number : "+ Integer.toString(devCount));

    D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[] deviceList = new D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[devCount];
    ftD2xx.getDeviceInfoList(devCount, deviceList);

    if(devCount <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    if(ftDev == null) {
        ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, 0);
    } else {
        synchronized (ftDev) {
            ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, 0);
        }
    }
    ...

} catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException ex) {
    Log.e(TAG,ex.toString());
}
```